# Android compilation

Tags: android

I have galaxy s1, and I wanna use it as test bed, is it ok to get any version of android from google and compile it and install it?

Am I gonna have problem with some of the driver?

I really appreciate it if someone can share anything with me that helps with the compilation and the installation.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. However you could try custom ROMS, from XDA-developers for example.

Comment: This is a bad question but why is it not possible? Maybe I don't understand what the user is asking

Comment: He's asking to download and compile android from source and use that to install different versions of Android. This isn't possible in the simplest sense in that you can just install it, the software needs to be properly tweaked to run on the device as software is completely device specific. So people like cyanogenmod etc can't release one ROM for every device. If this were possible however it would be awesome. Reasons it doesn't work are kernel and many many others.

Comment: OK, +1 to you. I understand that, I just didn't understand what they were asking because it sounded a little bizarre to me